# Azure Data Factory Cannot Read Metadata Folder

Tags: metadata, etl, azure-data-factory

I hope you guys keep health and keep strong in Pandemic covid-19.

I have some question on Azure Data Factory. btw I have create some pipeline with Metadata activity with detail below:

I have file in Folder and Subfolder like this:

[image]

1. I have metadata activity with for each with first get metadata child item (in folder) like this:

[image]

2. metadata with last modified like this (if you setting like this, metadata only read last modified subfolder
   [image]
3. after that add variable I use `@item().Name` to read file in that folder like this:
   [image]

after running metadata which have subfolder, I've get error like this:
the error give info that with `@item().Name` cannot read subfolder on that folder. the metadata for each file is success, but error like this which on my activity cannot read metadata subfolder .
[image]

many big thanks to have answer, Thank You

Comment: Apparently you have to use 2 variables or parameters for the dataset, folder and filename. Identify the item using type, if folder or file and then update dataset property accordingly. Let me know if you need an example setup

Comment: Are these files on windows machine accessed using SHIR ?

Comment: I'm using parameter on that data set. FileName is parameter ...

Comment: Yes, this machine using IR-Selfhosted ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to access the **folder**

Create a clone of same dataset and setup parameter as below, leave the `file` field empty.

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you need to access the **file** inside directory, use condition `@equals(item().type,'Folder')` to identity directory then inside that use dataset with parameters for directory and file.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok, I will try your solution, Thanks.